# Qualitatively new phenomena with $4$ dimensional dynamical systems?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

When studying [dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) with continuous variables, moving from $1$ dimension to $2$ to $3$ introduces qualitatively different phenomena (under certain conditions):

- going from $n=1$ to $n=2$, introduces the possibility of cyclical systems.
- going from $n=2$ to $n=3$, introduces the possibility of [chaotic behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory).

> Are there any qualitatively different phenomena introduced by going from $n=3$ to $n=4$, i.e. phenomena that cannot occur in $n=3$?

Comment: Well, when $n = 4$ a _hyperchaos_ becomes possible. I don't know very much about this phenomenon, but I think [this Scholarpedia reference](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hyperchaos#Reminiscences_about_the_discovery_of_hyperchaos) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you. That's the kind of answer I was looking for. I hope more answers will come.

Comment: @Programmer2134 nice question, I hope a bounty will help to gather more information! I am also interested in learning more about this.

Comment: I read the scholarpedia reference, and I have to ask how "hyperchaos" is significatively different from "regular chaos"...

Comment: @iadvd, Thank you. I'd want to top up the bounty, by adding some of my own. Is that possible?

Comment: @Programmer2134 just in case: probably you already know that you can try to answer your own questions. MSE encourages the users to answer their own questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer .So if your answer shows enough and fair effort gathering new information (for instance since you made the question you have learned more about the topic so you have clearer ideas now) you can also try to obtain the offered bounty in equal conditions as any other user.

Comment: @iadvd, yes I know, but no I haven't really studied this after asking the question. This was very explorative, though I will likely study it at some point in the future.

Comment: @Programmer2134 well we tried our best, I hope that even if the bounty finishes somebody will in the future provide more insights about this, good luck!